# Android studio error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource name cannot be empty

Tags: android, layout, resources

I am attempting to reopen an older Android Studio project in version 3.0.

It compiles and launches just fine, but if I try to edit a layout in the layout designer, it won't load and simply keeps saying that it is waiting for the build to finish (which it has).

When I look in the IDE errors, I see this error:

```
provider: org.jetbrains.android.augment.AndroidPsiAugmentProvider@2180343: Resource name cannot be empty.
```

As I look though the trace info, I see nothing that points back at my project.

Any suggestions?

Here is the full trace output:

```
provider: org.jetbrains.android.augment.AndroidPsiAugmentProvider@2180343: Resource name cannot be empty.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource name cannot be empty.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:122)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceItem.<init>(ResourceItem.java:115)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.IdGeneratingResourceParser$IdResourceItem.<init>(IdGeneratingResourceParser.java:202)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.IdGeneratingResourceParser.<init>(IdGeneratingResourceParser.java:81)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.createResourceFile(ResourceSet.java:456)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.createFileAndItems(ResourceSet.java:111)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.handleNewFile(ResourceSet.java:257)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.handleNewFile(ResourceSet.java:52)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataSet.loadFile(DataSet.java:275)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceFolderRepository$InitialScanState.loadFile(ResourceFolderRepository.java:325)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceFolderRepository.scanFileResourceFile(ResourceFolderRepository.java:524)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceFolderRepository.scanFileResourceFolder(ResourceFolderRepository.java:477)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceFolderRepository.scanResFolder(ResourceFolderRepository.java:449)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceFolderRepository.scanRemainingFiles(ResourceFolderRepository.java:375)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceFolderRepository.<init>(ResourceFolderRepository.java:119)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceFolderRepository.create(ResourceFolderRepository.java:152)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceFolderRegistry.get(ResourceFolderRegistry.java:76)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceFolderRegistry.get(ResourceFolderRegistry.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ModuleResourceRepository.create(ModuleResourceRepository.java:95)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceRepositories.lambda$getModuleResources$2(ResourceRepositories.java:98)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:942)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceRepositories.getModuleResources(ResourceRepositories.java:95)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ModuleResourceRepository.findModuleResources(ModuleResourceRepository.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ModuleResourceRepository.getOrCreateInstance(ModuleResourceRepository.java:59)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ProjectResourceRepository.computeRepositories(ProjectResourceRepository.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ProjectResourceRepository.create(ProjectResourceRepository.java:73)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceRepositories.lambda$getProjectResources$1(ResourceRepositories.java:83)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:942)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceRepositories.getProjectResources(ResourceRepositories.java:80)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ProjectResourceRepository.findProjectResources(ProjectResourceRepository.java:63)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ProjectResourceRepository.getOrCreateInstance(ProjectResourceRepository.java:51)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.AppResourceRepository.computeRepositories(AppResourceRepository.java:156)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.AppResourceRepository.create(AppResourceRepository.java:123)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceRepositories.lambda$getAppResources$0(ResourceRepositories.java:68)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:942)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceRepositories.getAppResources(ResourceRepositories.java:65)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.AppResourceRepository.findAppResources(AppResourceRepository.java:117)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.AppResourceRepository.getOrCreateInstance(AppResourceRepository.java:99)
    at org.jetbrains.android.dom.converters.ResourceReferenceConverter.getResourceTypesInCurrentModule(ResourceReferenceConverter.java:262)
    at org.jetbrains.android.augment.AndroidPsiAugmentProvider.getAugments(AndroidPsiAugmentProvider.java:67)
    at com.intellij.psi.augment.PsiAugmentProvider.lambda$collectAugments$0(PsiAugmentProvider.java:93)
    at com.intellij.psi.augment.PsiAugmentProvider.forEach(PsiAugmentProvider.java:137)
    at com.intellij.psi.augment.PsiAugmentProvider.collectAugments(PsiAugmentProvider.java:92)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.ClassInnerStuffCache.getAllInnerClasses(ClassInnerStuffCache.java:139)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.ClassInnerStuffCache.lambda$getInnerClasses$3(ClassInnerStuffCache.java:72)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.lambda$getCachedValue$0(CachedValuesManager.java:141)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.doCompute(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:49)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:222)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValue.getValueWithLock(PsiCachedValue.java:60)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.getValue(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:38)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.ClassInnerStuffCache.getInnerClasses(ClassInnerStuffCache.java:71)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.ClassInnerStuffCache.getInnerClassesMap(ClassInnerStuffCache.java:182)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.ClassInnerStuffCache.lambda$findInnerClassByName$6(ClassInnerStuffCache.java:102)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.lambda$getCachedValue$0(CachedValuesManager.java:141)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.doCompute(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:49)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:222)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValue.getValueWithLock(PsiCachedValue.java:60)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.getValue(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:38)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.ClassInnerStuffCache.findInnerClassByName(ClassInnerStuffCache.java:101)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiClassImpl.findInnerClassByName(PsiClassImpl.java:396)
    at org.jetbrains.android.util.AndroidResourceUtil.findResourceFieldsFromClass(AndroidResourceUtil.java:190)
    at org.jetbrains.android.util.AndroidResourceUtil.findResourceFields(AndroidResourceUtil.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.android.util.AndroidResourceUtil.findResourceFields(AndroidResourceUtil.java:168)
    at org.jetbrains.android.AndroidGotoRelatedProvider.collectRelatedJavaFiles(AndroidGotoRelatedProvider.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.android.AndroidGotoRelatedProvider.getLazyItemsForXmlFile(AndroidGotoRelatedProvider.java:112)
    at org.jetbrains.android.AndroidLineMarkerProvider.getMarkerInfo(AndroidLineMarkerProvider.java:91)
    at org.jetbrains.android.AndroidLineMarkerProvider.doGetLineMarkerInfo(AndroidLineMarkerProvider.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.android.AndroidLineMarkerProvider.collectSlowLineMarkers(AndroidLineMarkerProvider.java:37)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.queryProviders(LineMarkersPass.java:209)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.lambda$doCollectInformation$3(LineMarkersPass.java:111)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.Divider.divideInsideAndOutsideInOneRoot(Divider.java:96)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.doCollectInformation(LineMarkersPass.java:106)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:70)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$null$1(PassExecutorService.java:438)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1156)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$2(PassExecutorService.java:431)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:430)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$run$0(PassExecutorService.java:406)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:242)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:404)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:165)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)


java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource name cannot be empty.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:122)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceItem.<init>(ResourceItem.java:115)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.IdGeneratingResourceParser$IdResourceItem.<init>(IdGeneratingResourceParser.java:202)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.IdGeneratingResourceParser.<init>(IdGeneratingResourceParser.java:81)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.createResourceFile(ResourceSet.java:456)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.createFileAndItems(ResourceSet.java:111)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.handleNewFile(ResourceSet.java:257)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.handleNewFile(ResourceSet.java:52)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataSet.loadFile(DataSet.java:275)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceFolderRepository$InitialScanState.loadFile(ResourceFolderRepository.java:325)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceFolderRepository.scanFileResourceFile(ResourceFolderRepository.java:524)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceFolderRepository.scanFileResourceFolder(ResourceFolderRepository.java:477)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceFolderRepository.scanResFolder(ResourceFolderRepository.java:449)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceFolderRepository.scanRemainingFiles(ResourceFolderRepository.java:375)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceFolderRepository.<init>(ResourceFolderRepository.java:119)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceFolderRepository.create(ResourceFolderRepository.java:152)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceFolderRegistry.get(ResourceFolderRegistry.java:76)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceFolderRegistry.get(ResourceFolderRegistry.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ModuleResourceRepository.create(ModuleResourceRepository.java:95)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceRepositories.lambda$getModuleResources$2(ResourceRepositories.java:98)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:942)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceRepositories.getModuleResources(ResourceRepositories.java:95)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ModuleResourceRepository.findModuleResources(ModuleResourceRepository.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ModuleResourceRepository.getOrCreateInstance(ModuleResourceRepository.java:59)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ProjectResourceRepository.computeRepositories(ProjectResourceRepository.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ProjectResourceRepository.create(ProjectResourceRepository.java:73)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceRepositories.lambda$getProjectResources$1(ResourceRepositories.java:83)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:942)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceRepositories.getProjectResources(ResourceRepositories.java:80)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ProjectResourceRepository.findProjectResources(ProjectResourceRepository.java:63)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ProjectResourceRepository.getOrCreateInstance(ProjectResourceRepository.java:51)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.AppResourceRepository.computeRepositories(AppResourceRepository.java:156)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.AppResourceRepository.create(AppResourceRepository.java:123)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceRepositories.lambda$getAppResources$0(ResourceRepositories.java:68)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:942)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceRepositories.getAppResources(ResourceRepositories.java:65)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.AppResourceRepository.findAppResources(AppResourceRepository.java:117)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.AppResourceRepository.getOrCreateInstance(AppResourceRepository.java:99)
    at org.jetbrains.android.resourceManagers.LocalResourceManager.getResourceNames(LocalResourceManager.java:261)
    at org.jetbrains.android.resourceManagers.ResourceManager.getResourceNames(ResourceManager.java:349)
    at org.jetbrains.android.augment.ResourceTypeClassBase.buildResourceFields(ResourceTypeClassBase.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.android.augment.ResourceTypeClass.buildLocalResourceFields(ResourceTypeClass.java:30)
    at org.jetbrains.android.augment.AndroidPsiAugmentProvider.getAugments(AndroidPsiAugmentProvider.java:107)
    at com.intellij.psi.augment.PsiAugmentProvider.lambda$collectAugments$0(PsiAugmentProvider.java:93)
    at com.intellij.psi.augment.PsiAugmentProvider.forEach(PsiAugmentProvider.java:137)
    at com.intellij.psi.augment.PsiAugmentProvider.collectAugments(PsiAugmentProvider.java:92)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.ClassInnerStuffCache.getAllFields(ClassInnerStuffCache.java:125)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.ClassInnerStuffCache.lambda$getFields$1(ClassInnerStuffCache.java:60)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.lambda$getCachedValue$0(CachedValuesManager.java:141)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.doCompute(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:49)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:222)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValue.getValueWithLock(PsiCachedValue.java:60)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.getValue(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:38)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.ClassInnerStuffCache.getFields(ClassInnerStuffCache.java:59)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.ClassInnerStuffCache.getFieldsMap(ClassInnerStuffCache.java:145)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.ClassInnerStuffCache.lambda$findFieldByName$4(ClassInnerStuffCache.java:82)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.lambda$getCachedValue$0(CachedValuesManager.java:141)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.doCompute(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:49)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:222)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValue.getValueWithLock(PsiCachedValue.java:60)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.getValue(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:38)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.ClassInnerStuffCache.findFieldByName(ClassInnerStuffCache.java:80)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiClassImpl.findFieldByName(PsiClassImpl.java:362)
    at org.jetbrains.android.util.AndroidResourceUtil.findResourceFieldsFromClass(AndroidResourceUtil.java:195)
    at org.jetbrains.android.util.AndroidResourceUtil.findResourceFields(AndroidResourceUtil.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.android.util.AndroidResourceUtil.findResourceFields(AndroidResourceUtil.java:168)
    at org.jetbrains.android.AndroidGotoRelatedProvider.collectRelatedJavaFiles(AndroidGotoRelatedProvider.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.android.AndroidGotoRelatedProvider.getLazyItemsForXmlFile(AndroidGotoRelatedProvider.java:112)
    at org.jetbrains.android.AndroidLineMarkerProvider.getMarkerInfo(AndroidLineMarkerProvider.java:91)
    at org.jetbrains.android.AndroidLineMarkerProvider.doGetLineMarkerInfo(AndroidLineMarkerProvider.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.android.AndroidLineMarkerProvider.collectSlowLineMarkers(AndroidLineMarkerProvider.java:37)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.queryProviders(LineMarkersPass.java:209)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.lambda$doCollectInformation$3(LineMarkersPass.java:111)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.Divider.divideInsideAndOutsideInOneRoot(Divider.java:96)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.doCollectInformation(LineMarkersPass.java:106)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:70)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$null$1(PassExecutorService.java:438)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1156)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$2(PassExecutorService.java:431)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:430)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$run$0(PassExecutorService.java:406)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:242)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:404)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:165)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Update:
I have not found a solution yet, but a coworker working on another project (from which I forked my project) has just had the same thing happen to him. This leads me to think this may be project specific. However, none of the error trace shows anything in our project. This obviously makes it hard to diagnose.

Comment: having the same problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error can occur when you update to Android Studio 3.0.  It doesn't affect your ability to build a project, but the error does not allow you to visually see your xml layout files.  You will also get the error when committing files to GIT, but you can still commit and push.

What I found in one of my projects is that a file was added to the "menu" folder automatically upon Android Studio upgrade, and the file had no name.  It was named simply ".xml".  All you need to do is delete the file and clean your project, allowing a new build of the project.  That should take care of the issue.

Comment: Issue is tracked [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69094358)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try it like this:
go to setting in AndroidStudio and change values like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAO5Z.png).

Then click ok.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File>Invalidate Caches / Restart.

It might help!
Thank you!

Comment: I have tried that after every change I have made, and no luck yet.

Comment: Have you copied an image to your project recently??

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix it by Uninstall **Android Studio 3.0** and installed **Android Studio 3.1.** Its working fine.

Comment: Did you mean Android Studio 3.0.1 ?
3.1 seems to be available only as of [15th Feb 2018] (https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/02/android-studio-31-beta-3-is-now.html) (Crap ! Link formatting not detected !)
Anyway, I have the same problem in 3.0.1 ..;/

Comment: i have tested on canary https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/10/android-studio-31-canary-1-now-available.html

Comment: Okay, and what is you experience with canary ? Is it worthy the risk of getting newest bugs ? IMHO there are still enough bugs even in the stable channel, so I am a bit cautious :)